# Bison Multi-line Grammar

Tags: interpreter, bison, flex-lexer

Using the following `flex` and `bison` code, I can print the text `hello` when the command `print "Hello"` is inputted:

`flex file:`

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()
#include "gbison.tab.h"
%}
%%
[ \t\n]            ;
[a-zA-Z0-9]+       { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return STRING; }
\"(\\.|[^"])*\"    { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return QUOTED_STRING; }
%%
```

`bison file:`

```
%{
#include <cstdio> 
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int yylex();
extern "C" int yyparse();
extern "C" FILE* yyin;

void yyerror (const char* s);
%}

%union {
  char* sval;
}

%token <sval> STRING
%token <sval> QUOTED_STRING
%%

str:
    STRING QUOTED_STRING
    {
       if (strcmp($1, "print") == 0)
       {
           cout << $2 << flush;
       }
       if (strcmp($1, "println") == 0)
       {
           cout << $3 << endl; 
       }
    }
    ;
%%

main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   FILE* input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if (!input)
   {
      cout << "Bad input. Nonexistant file" << endl; 
      return -1;
   } 

   yyin = input;

   do 
   {
       yyparse();
   } while (!feof(yyin));

}
void yyerror(const char* s)
{
   cout << "Error. " << s << endl; 
   exit(-1);   
}
```

How would I change the `Bison grammar` so that it would not have a *syntax error* if there is more than one print or println command?

Comment: Please be careful of tagging...  Flex is for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework.  Flex-lexer is for the lexical analyzer.

Comment: @Reboog711 Got it. Didn't realize that `flex` is for Adobe/Apache Flex, not the `flex-lexer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the grammar before the first `%%` line:

```
%start list
```

and add to the grammar just after the first `%%` line:

```
list:
        /* Nothing */
    |   list str
    ;
```

This says that the complete grammar consists of a list, and a list is nothing (empty input) or a list followed by a 'str'.

As it stood, your grammar said that the valid inputs consisted of exactly one occurrence of 'str', hence the syntax error when you started to repeat yourself.